# How to count how many categories a post have in Wordpress?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

If a post has "Banana", "Orange", and "Kiwi" as categories, how can I know that the total number of categories in this post are 3?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `get_the_category` within your post loop :

```
<?php
$post = get_post();
if ( $post ) {
    $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    var_dump( $categories );
}
```

then `$categories` will contain all your categories related to this post. You only have to use `count($categories)` to get the number.

Comment: Please don't answer low-quality questions like this.  Questions are supposed to show the relevant code, as well as show research effort.